# Pyspark bizare behavior when dropDruplicates

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm using pyspark (Apache Spark v.3.2.1) on Databricks platform to make some data cleaning and transformations on dataset with around 150 million records. I'm getting some bizarre results which I cannot understand. Let's say that my dataframe `df` have columns : Column_1, Column_2, Column_3, Column_4, and I want to clean it in two steps.

```
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(my_table_path)    
df = df.dropDuplicates(("Column_1", "Column_2"))
logger.info("No. of records after first drop: {}".format(df.count()))
df = df.dropDuplicates(("Column_1", "Column_3"))
logger.info("No. of records after second drop: {}".format(df.count()))
```

Weirdly I'm getting results like (of course the difference is smaller, but I want to just make a point):

```
No. of records after first drop: 140000000
No. of records after second drop: 145000000
```

In my thinking number of rows after my second dropping of duplicates should always be lower or equal to result from first drop.
What I miss?

Comment: just curious, [`dropDuplicates()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-dropduplicates) takes in a list of columns (or nothing) -- how did your code work correctly?

Comment: @samkart My bad, I forget about second pair of brackets during writing ticket :) Already fixed it